# Counting Alphabetic Characters That Are Contained in an Array with C

Tags: c, search, arrays, char

I am having trouble with a homework question that I've been working at for quite some time.
I don't know exactly why the question is asking and need some clarification on that and also a push in the right direction.

Here is the question:

> (2) Solve this problem using one single subscripted array of counters.  The program uses an array of characters defined using the C initialization feature. The program counts the number of each of the alphabetic characters a to z (only lower case characters are counted)  and prints a report  (in a neat table) of the number of occurrences of each lower case character found. Only print the counts for the letters that occur at least once. That is do not print a count if it is zero. DO NOT use a switch statement in your solution. NOTE: if x is of type char, x-‘a’ is the difference between the ASCII codes for the character in x and the character ‘a’.  For example if x holds the character ‘c’ then x-‘a’ has the value 2, while if x holds the character ‘d’, then x-‘a’ has the value 3. Provide test results using the following string:
>
> “This is an example  of  text for exercise (2).”

And here is my source code so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

    char c[] = "This is an example of text for exercise (2).";
    char d[26];
    
    int i;
    int j = 0;
    int k;
    
    j = 0;

    //char s = 97;

    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(c); i++) {
        for(s = 'a'; s < 'z'; s++){
            if( c[i] == s){
                
                k++;
                printf("%c,%d\n", s, k);
                k = 0;

            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
    
}
```

As you can see, my current solution is a little anemic.
Thanks for the help, and I know everyone on the net doesn't necessarily like helping with other people's homework. ;P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char c[] = "This is an example of text for exercise (2).";
int d[26] = {0}, i, value;

for(i=0; i < sizeof(c) - 1; i++){ //-1 to exclude terminating NULL
   value = c[i]-'a';
   if(value < 26 && value >= 0) d[value]++;
}

for(i=0; i < 26; i++){
   if(d[i]) printf("Alphabet-%c Count-%d\n", 'a'+i, d[i]);
}
```

---

Corrected. Thanks caf and Leffler.

Comment: Thank you, I see how I was trying to over complicate the answer.

Comment: This solution writes outside of the defined bounds of the array `d`.

Comment: That has problems - what about the spaces, parentheses, digit, dots (and terminal NUL)?

Comment: It still writes outside of the array - `c[i] - 'a'` might be negative (for example for `'T'` and `' '`).

Comment: @nvl: you should use `isalpha` or `islower`.

Comment: @Alok: maybe.  As long as the program doesn't do 'setlocale("");', using 'islower()' is safe enough - the locale will be the C locale.  Using 'isalpha()' is not a good idea; the capital T is to be ignored.  You'd then rewrite the loop with `'if (islower(c[i])) d[c[i]-'a']++;`' in the body.  You might or might not add an '(unsigned char)' cast to the argument to 'islower()'; it won't hurt with the test data, but with signed char and accented characters in 8859-1 or 8859-15 code sets, it would matter.

Comment: @Jonathan: yeah, I wasn't thinking properly when I wrote the above.  As you said, `isalpha()` doesn't really buy one anything, and `islower()` is also of limited use here.  Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

The intention of the question is for you to figure out how to efficiently convert a character between `'a'` and `'z'` into an index between 0 and 25.  You are apparently allowed to assume ASCII for this (although the C standard does not guarantee any particular character set), which has the useful property that values of the characters `'a'` through `'z'` are sequential.

Once you've done that, you can increment the corresponding slot in your array `d` (note that you will need to initialise that array to all-zeroes to begin with, which can be done simply with `char d[26] = { 0 };`.  At the end, you'd scan through the array `d` and print the counts out that are greater than zero, along with the corresponding character (which will involve the reverse transformation - from an index 0 through 25 into a character `'a'` through `'z'`).

Answer (score 2):

Fortunately for you, you do not seem to be required to produce a solution that would work on an EBCDIC machine (mainframe).

Your inner loop needs to be replaced by a conditional:

```
if (c[i] is lower-case alphabetic)
    increment the appropriate count in the d-array
```

After finishing the string, you then need a loop to scan through the d-array, printing out the letter corresponding to the entry and the count associated with it.

Your d-array uses 'char' for the counts; that is OK for the exercise but you would probably need to use a bigger integer type for a general purpose solution.  You should also ensure that it is initialized to all zeros; it is difficult to get meaningful information out of random garbage (and the language does not guarantee that anything other than garbage will be on the stack where the d-array is stored).

Answer (score 0):

.

```
for(s = 'a'; s < 'z'; s++){ 
    j=0;
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(c); i++) { 
         if( c[i] == s )
            j++;
    }
    if (j > 0)
        printf("%c,%d\n", s, j); 
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about any of this?  Did you try running it?

Comment: I ran it and there are a few missing brackets on the if statement but besides some little syntax errors it is fine.

Comment: OK - I confused myself by treating the indentation as accurate.  One more reason not to like K&R placement of braces.

Comment: This algorithm scans the string 26 times.  For a short string, this is  not a problem.  If the data had to be read from a file, or if the string was multiple megabytes in size, then it might be a problem compared with the solutions that scan the data just once.  But it is an interesting alternative way to look at the problem - for each interesting character (letter), count the number of times it occurs, and print the character and the count if it appears at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
char c[] = "This is an example of text for exercise (2).";
char d[26];
int i;
int j;

for(i = 0; i < 26; i++)
{
    d[i] = 0; // Set the frequency of the letter to zero before we start counting.
    for(j = 0; j < strlen(c); j++)
    {
        if(c[j] == i + 'a')
            d[i]++;
    }
    if(d[i] > 0) // If the frequency of the letter is greater than 0, show it.
        printf("%c - %d\n", (i + 'a'), d[i]);
}
```